# Customize lock screen

Tags: android, customization, lockscreen

how can I customize the default android lock screen like spotify does? I.e. I want to add some buttons to control my app from the lock screen. It has to be compatible with JB 4.1.

Comment: From our good friend Google: http://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/put-your-key-apps-on-the-android-lock-screen-for-easy-a-1621573474

Comment: @M0CH1R0N "Lock screen widgets have been around since Android 4.2"

Read my post pls. And that post doesn't explain me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Android's only built-in lock screen controls are for media playback. If this is what you're looking for, check out [MediaSession](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html) for API 21 and above, or [RemoteControlClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) for lower API versions.

If you want to do more, check out the [Adenda](http://www.adendamedia.com/) SDK. Lock screen widgets were deprecated in Android 5.0 and above. So it essentially extends the Android stack to let you design and program your layouts on the lock screen like you would with any other app, and feed them into the SDK.

For example:

```
AdendaAgent.addCustomFragmentContent (Context context, String actionToPerformOnUnlock, String your.fragment.name, Bundle fragmentArgs, String identifier, boolean bDisplayUntilCancelled)
```

I'm affiliated with Adenda for full disclosure.